# scrollable table + overflow-x

Tags: css, scrollable-table

I am currently testing multiple behaviors of the  element and one is particularly challenging.

Objective: prepare a table with a fixed  and a  with a fixed height and scroll-y. (this has been done)

Limitation: the table is huge and extends out of the browser window (therefore only visible by scrolling horizontally in the browser).

The issue: when the table extends out of the browser window, the specified widths are not okay anymore and the  are not vertically aligned with the .

Exemple here : http://codepen.io/Carine/pen/xqKDa

What do you think? Have you encountered this problem before?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you provide more info? What do you mean by 'the specified widths are not okay anymore and the are not vertically aligned with the .'

Comment: try min/max-width, here's your modified example:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kIxnz

Answer (score 1):

Add min-width & max-width properties:

try this:

```
th, td {
  width: 160px;
  max-width:160px;
  min-width:160px;  
}
```

Comment: @Carine: I'm glad I could help... please mark it as answer so that others would get in one go :)